# Wordpress form link broken

Tags: wordpress, forms, twitter-bootstrap, form-submit

I have a pre-form on a Wordpress site (localhost) where users submit their name, email, etc., before continuing to the first part of a multi-page quiz.

The problem is, if I enter any details, Wordpress directs to a 404 page. But if I leave them blank (obviously I want to make these required fields) then it directs to the next page all ok.

I have checked my .htaccess file, Apache settings and followed all the other possible solutions I have found on SO and elsewhere, but nothing I have found fixes the issue.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="pre-quiz">
    <form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/part-1" method="post">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="First name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Last name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="business" id="business" placeholder="Business name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email address">
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control px-4 pb-4 pt-2">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="terms" id="terms" value="terms">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="terms">
                I accept the <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/terms">Terms of Use</a> &amp; <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/privacy">Privacy Policy</a>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block">Next step</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don`t see any error. Try to name your checkbox not "terms", maybe there is a conflict.

Regards Tom

Comment: Thanks for the rapid reply, Tom, but unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: Oh, I' m sorry. I thought this is a possible reason because there is already a page named `/terms` and because the terms variable could be used by your theme somehow.

Comment: No worries! If only it was that simple.

Comment: Can you do a `echo bloginfo('url');` somewhere to debug?

Comment: I can do, but the same link structure works on other pages in the form. I don't know if it makes a difference that all the other pages are radio buttons/checkboxes and range sliders and this is the only page with text inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Tom, I took your idea and tried it with all the other fields to see if Wordpress was using 'name' or 'email' and changed them to something unique - It worked! Thanks again for your input.